# How to get column name in array?

Tags: php

I have a script where I want to get name of a column in `array()`.
From API, I can get an `array()` with multiple values and I would like to get the name of a specific column.

I don't have columns' names, how do I get a list of them and fetch one by one?
Here, I want to get "573" only.

```
Array ( [success] => 1 [errors] => Array ( ) [data] => Array ( [Messages] => Array ( [573] => PHP is fun ) ) )
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what a sample array looks like

Comment: Do you want to get all columns under messages? Or do you want to search for a particular column, for example search for 573 and get the result as PHP is fun?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do a recursive iterator that will use itself to recurse or return a value based on the key match:

```
<?php
$arr    =   array(
                'success' => 1,
                'errors' => array(),
                'data' => array(
                    'Messages' => array(
                        573 => 'PHP is fun'
                    )
                )
            );

function recurseIt($array,$find = false)
    {
        # Loop through array
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            # If the key is the same as the value
            if($key == $find)
                # Send back the value
                return $value;
            # If the value is an array
            if(is_array($value)) {
                # Use same array to recurse the array
                $val    =   recurseIt($value,$find);
                # If there is a value to return
                if(!empty($val))
                    # Send it back
                    return $val;
            }
        }
    }
# Note, if the key matches, could also be an array
echo recurseIt($arr,573);
```

Gives you:

```
PHP is fun
```

**EDIT:**

Presumably you have the value if you don't know the key, so this will return the key based on the search value:

```
function recurseIt($array,$find = false)
    {
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            # If the key is the same as the value
            if(!is_array($value) && ($value == $find))
                # Send back the key name
                return $key;
            if(is_array($value)) {
                $val    =   recurseIt($value,$find);
                if(!empty($val))
                    return $val;
            }
        }
    }

echo recurseIt($arr,'PHP is fun');
```

Gives you:

```
573
```

Now, if you don't know what the key name is and don't know the associated value would be, then the function doesn't know how to search. `read_my_mind()` is not yet in the PHP library so at that point you are pretty much out of luck.

Comment: I do not know the number 573 and I wish I could get it.

Comment: So you know the value of 573? You need to to be able to search the array for something so if it's not the key, then you would have to search for the value and return the key